# Can Allure reports be implemented with TestNG without using Maven?

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, reporting, allure

Can Allure reports be implemented with TestNG without using Maven?

I just want to get allure reports without maven. Is there any possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yest, this is possible. Just get the jar and add it to your project's class path. That's all. You can get the jar from here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.allure/allure-testng-adaptor/1.2.2

Comment: Thanks!! but can i know where can i see the reports? I mean index.html file of allure reports.

Comment: You can specify it in property file or use defaults. To genreate report just run Allure CLI.

Comment: @RamaKrishna allure report is not generated while you execute your tests, the suggested adaptor is used to collect data about test execution. Once test are done, you can execute report generation.